# I want to develop in Go on Windows and deploy to Google App Engine

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, go

I want to develop in the Go Language (go-lang) using Google App Engine to run my app and I use IntelliJ on Windows. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the official installer, it is very easy to get [Go up and running](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=6615) on Windows.

Edit: The latest [Zeus beta](http://www.zeusedit.com/go.html) now has support for the Go Build, Format and Run commands and also does Go initellisene (i.e. auto complete).

Answer (score 3):

Edit, Jun 2012: As at the 1.7 version, there is now experimental support for windows:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads

The Go App-Engine development server is available for Linux and Mac only [1].  The Go language is available for Windows, but not the app-engine tools.  I imagine it would be possible to port the GAE dev server to run under windows, because it just uses python, go and sqlite, but I don't think anyone has done so.

Of course you can run a linux virtual machine, or remote into a linux server to do the development.  You could even edit in windows using sftp if your editor supports it.

[[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Go](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Go)

Answer (score 2):

You can find golang builds for Windows [here](http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/list%20here). Golang is primarily focusing on unix-like OSs (golang devs are from bell labs), but while writing an application for appengine you won't hit any issues because you're using a Window's version. The appengine platform doesn't let you do things like manipulate files: instead you use the appengine's datastore/blobstore to store things. The main issues the Window's golang port are related to simply operating system functionality and since you won't be using any on appengine, there's no issue.

As for an IDE on Windows that has code completion, goclipse probably has the most "out of the box"; it's distributed with golang plugins and autocompletion. Golang itself is distributed with plug-ins/configs for the most popular editors (vim, emacs, sublime, etc...). You can use pretty much any popular editor with [nsf's gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode) for autocompletion if you want to take a little time to set things up.

The development for golang is pretty quick; I'm actually turned off from using appengine until it supports Go 1. There are some big changes between r60 and the current golang. Most libraries are keeping up to date with the quick golang development, which causes some pains using r60 golang.

Comment: That's great but two questions, can I use the Google App Engine libraries by doing this? Can I deploy to Google App Engine by doing this?

Comment: Yeah, if you use the r60 (release) build of Go and check out the  [appengine docs](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/). Deploying just takes some yaml configurations and the use of a appengine tool written in python. You also need to remember to package any libraries that you use with the project so that appengine's compiler can compile everything. I'd just follow the documentation that I linked and you shouldn't hit any issues just because you're developing on Windows.

Comment: The Go App Engine SDK has not been ported to Windows, as kristianp's answer describes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Windows version of the go toolset, you will have to install that from [golang.org](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsSupport).

You can start with [goclipse](https://code.google.com/p/goclipse/). If you don't like Eclipse, then you can use Emacs (available from gnu.org) for Windows; or any editor that you like.

Go on Windows isn't fully supported yet. Another option would be to download Virtual Box; install Linux on a virtual machine and use that as your development machine.